# Transferable magical talents and and a man forced to shave a sea captain

Tags: story-identification, magic

Since this was many years ago I only remember bits and pieces of the book.  I recall the magic system was talents. Certain people would have talents and you could somehow take those talents away from others.  Any ideas?

The only other things I can remember are something about the protagonist being forced to shave a guy (the captain?) on his ship, being certain not to nick the guy, and a big finale at the end...maybe some kind of fight.

Comment: Might need more detail than that.

Comment: To expound on what gnovice said, any information you can provide will be helpful. Approximate year range when you read it, what was on the cover, information about the plot or sub-plots, etc. Anything you remember helps, no matter how small.

Comment: Could it be the [Xanth Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanth)?

Comment: It might be the Xanth Series, but I don't think so.  I'm not positive, but I believe it's a stand-alone book.  The only other things I can remember is something about the protagonist being forced to shave a guy (the captain?) on his ship.  He was to make certain not to knick the guy.  I also remember a big finale at the end...maybe some kind of fight.

Comment: Sounds like the Earthdawn setting.  The book may be [Scars](http://www.perasperapress.com/media/lostearthdawn/scars_excerpt.pdf) or "Worlds Without End" which is a sequel to Scars.

Comment: If you think you know what it might be, add that information as an answer, ideally with a bit of information about why you think it matches and a link to ISFDB/Amazon/Google Books/etc.  Even if it's not the one the asker is looking for, it might help someone in the future who is trying to identify something similar. (Plus, this way you get reputation for your suggestion!).

Comment: _and a big finale at the end...maybe some kind of fight_ can't think of any stories like that, sorry bud 

Answer (score 7):

I'm very late to this question, so I don't know if it's still relevant, but the description of magic sounds like [The Legend of Nightfall](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/129020.The_Legend_of_Nightfall).   To quote from a review of it:

> This has magic but of a type that you don't often seen in fantasy novels. Magic is an often innate ability to do one thing. Sorcerers are largely dangerous people that rip the souls from others to steal their innate gifts and use them.

I think I vaugely remember that scene about having to shave someone, but I couldn't tell you if it was this book or not. It's been years since I've read it.

Comment: The scene with the shaving happens in the sequel, *The Return of Nightfall*. He has to disguise a pirate captain first as an upper-class woman, then as a noble. Both required shaving him.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is the right answer, for all that the original querent seems to have disappeared, plus I like to promote the series. Congrats!

Comment: @SeanDuggan - Thank you.  I probably wouldn't have been able to answer the question at all if it were asked today, which is probably a sign I should go reread the books.  On my list they go!

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the [Night Angel Trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6122735-the-night-angel-trilogy?ac=1) where good magic if through Talents and bad magic is Vir. The Ka'Kari focused a users talent giving them a different powers depending on which Ka'Kari it was, with the Black Ka'Kari being the most powerful as it had the power of all the other Ka'Kari. There are different colours of Talent, which allow someone to use different kinds of magic.

Regarding your plot points, I can't remember specifically anything about shaving but I also can't specifically remember that not happening. It's plausible that it would fit into the plot when Blint is training Azoth.

Big finale with a fight? Well that could probably fit into 99% of fantasy books about magic..yes there was a big fight at the end, one that lasted a whole night IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

This reminds me the David Farland series [Runelords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Runelords).

> In the universe of The Runelords, there exists a unique magical system which relies on the existence of distinct bodily attributes, such as brawn, grace, and wit. These attributes can be transferred from one individual (or animal) to another in a process known as "giving an endowment". Lords who have taken many endowments become extremely powerful, almost superhuman, and are known as Runelords.

The endowments are transferred using a magical brand called a "forcible". The brand is applied to the skin, and probably requires a clear patch of skin necessitating the shaving.

Comment: Why? Can you explain in what sense Runelords is related to the question?

Comment: Just the transferrable magical abilities part, in fact : in Runelords, the lords can get the strength, intelligence,... of other people/animals by using forged runes.