# Looking for the title of a "Tad Williams" style book

Tags: story-identification

I read this book between 1996-1998. It was paperback, and actually quite thick. The artwork was something reminiscent of:

[image]
I don't think it was Tad Williams book, but the size of his paperbacks and the artwork are reference points. I believe that the main character was a swordsman looking for something. And the word "Night" is quite relevant, but I'm not certain how. I want to say that there was something about being skilled with a sword earned a rank or a sword or something.

I wish I had more to go on, but if I think of anything, I'll be sure to edit.

Comment: Luck in the Shadows by Lynn Flewelling (book 1 of Nightrunners)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luck_in_the_Shadows?

Comment: Honestly, we're going to need more info.  A swordsman looking for something that may have something to do with Night is pretty vague.  Late 90s epic (long) fantasy was pretty popular and the other details probably describe hundreds of books.

Comment: Note to reviewers:  OP has indicated in meta that they have identified the book, and want the question reopened so they can post an answer.

Comment: In ahead of them posting an answwer, it looks like this book also came up at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6808/23243

Comment: Was the cover art an abstract design, a photograph or derived from one, "high art" (e.g. your examples), or a cartoon?

Answer (score 4):

Putting in a placeholder answer until PiousVenom comes back and posts. They identified the book [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13946/am-i-allowed-to-edit-an-old-question-i-posted-that-has-been-closed) as Mickey Zucker Reichert's *[The Legend of Nightfall](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0886775876)*.

[image: Cover of The Legend of Nightfall]

> He has been known by countless names and terrifying deeds throughout the lands of mankind—thief, magic wielder, swordsman, assassin, adventurer. But chief among those names and perhaps the most dangerous of his personae is that of Nightfall, a man—or perhaps the legendary demon himself—gifted with unique powers which any sorcerer would kill to possess.
>
> Yet though Nightfall has always escaped his pursuers by moving on to new realms, new identities, and new enterprises, even the cleverest of beings must occasionally slip. And when this master of the night finally falls prey to a royal trap, he finds the consequences beyond even his ability to evade. Bound by sorcery and oath to guard and guide a young prince on his quest, Nightfall will need every trick and talent at his command to keep both himself and his idealistic young charge from death at the hands of unknown betrayers.

Answer (score 1):

The Swords of Night and Day: A Novel of Druss the Legend and Skilgannon the Damned (Drenai Saga: The Damned)

[image]

this one?

or possibly this one, the art looks really similar

[image]

Edit: added the second book cover.

Comment: Can you explain how this matches other than possibly the cover?

Comment: about swords, and the word night stands out, cover looks similar too. if the poster of the question can confirm its not the correct book i delete my post.